# Null Hypothesis question phrasing

Tags: statistics

If I want to determine if people like tea or coffee more and conduct a simple random survey of about 50 people, I have some confusion about how to phrase the question to the people and how that affects the Null Hypothesis.

If I say, "Do you like tea or coffee more?" then I'm not sure how to state the null.  If I say, "Do you like tea or coffee equally well?", then it is clear that the null would be mu = .5 and the alternative would be mu does not equal .5.

How would I set up the null for the first question of "Do you like tea or coffee?

I have read some articles that state journals don't like one sided tests (compared with two sided) unless the question is yes or no.  So, I'm confused about how to set the null and alternative for this simple experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it one-sided by saying: Do you like tea more than or as much as coffee? That means that yes implies that someone likes tea more than coffee or equally, and no implies someone like coffee more than tea.

So you get a statement like tea>=coffee, tea < coffee.

Would that help you?

Comment: Yes, I can see how that would work, but I wonder about the person truly understanding this Boolean type question

Comment: I think that you should consider what you want to show, do you want to show that someone prefers coffee more or significantly prefers coffee more. If you want to show significance of the difference in the two questions (coffee over tea or vice versa) , then you should look at two-sided tests, otherwise you can use one-sided tests. Your belief of the answer, for example : preference of coffee over tea, states the null-hypothesis. If you then want to show that coffee is indeed preferred over tea (although not significantly) you can use the one-sided test.